# Jade: How to include js file in a certain point

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

i want to include a file that must be used only when a jade file is render client side, this is the .jade file:

```
button(type="button")#start.flex
p#timer.flex
button(type="button" )#stop.flex
script(src='../public/js/timer.js')
```

The js file will handle the timer function, i have a console log in the .js file but it is never fired. What i'm doing wrong? I canno't import it in the head because the element won't be ready yet.

Thus i have to find a way to include and use timer.js only when this file is render. Thank you guys

Comment: Do you see the <script src="../public/js/timer.js"></script>  in the rendered HTML?  And if you use developer tools, network, do you see the script file loaded or do you see an http error somewhere?

Comment: yeah i see it in the html, but in network i don't see it

Comment: try this:  script(type='text/javascript' src='public/js/timer.js')

Comment: @Jared this doesn't work

Comment: Is this jade being rendered through AJAX or is this loaded with the entire document?

Comment: @Jared Yes it is render with AJAX

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript inserted as DOM text will not execute.

You must load the script file initially, with the document load.  When loading content via AJAX response, execute whatever javascript function or functions you want in the success handler.  There are other ways as well, but your current design wont work.

Checkout this link:
http://caih.org/open-source-software/modularjs/loading-javascript-script-vs-ajax-vs-both/